# Spring init failing when bean constructor using parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor

SpringBoot app fails while trying to initialize this class:

```
@Component
public class Weather {

private Map<Integer,Double> maxRainyDays;
private Map<Integer,  WeatherDays> totalDays;

public Weather(Map<Integer, WeatherDays> totalDays, Map<Integer,Double> maxRainyDays){

    this.setMaxRainyDays(maxRainyDays);
    this.setTotalDays(totalDays);

}
```

The error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in SolarSystem.Models.Weather required a
>   bean of type 'SolarSystem.Utilities.WeatherDays' that could not be
>   found.

The mentioned bean is already defined (in the same basepackage):

```
public enum WeatherDays {

RAINY,
MILD,
DRY,
MAX_RAIN}
```

**Workaround:**

When I changed to Weather() constructor I solved the issue.Of course I had to use setters to set the properties of the object.

**But I need to understand the reasons why happened**

Comment: This class doesn't look like it should be a bean (service object); instead, it looks like it's a data object.

Comment: Question, why do you consider to inject Weather as component?

Comment: @JonathanJohx because I'm autowiring into other Service in the package

Comment: Ok let me explain about it, first when you inject a Class in this context Weather as dependency then you need to pass an empty construct or a construct with parameters which they need to be injected as beans because when Spring scans all components, they should have an empty construct or parameters injected. Example public Weather (@Autowored Service service) {... }  when a class is injected as component is more or less like a singleton class..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it really helps. But I still have one doubt: 
When I instantiate Weather ...I would need to pass Service in the constructor right?

Comment: Yes, you need it. For that you need to know if it's  necessary creating a component called Weather or perhaps you need to create several instances from this Weather class.

Comment: For the record: Understanding **new(), constructors and beans** in Spring, this blog article **helped me a lot** !!

https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the collections (Map here) you are injecting via constructor parameter aren't registered as Spring beans. This is why you would annotate class with `@service`, `@repository`, etc and have them autowired into other classes. To fix, you can set up a config class like such:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<Integer, WeatherDays> totalDays() {
        Map<Integer, WeatherDays> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, WeatherDays.DRY);
        return map;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<Integer, Double> maxRainyDays() {
        Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, 0.2);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know! So this is how you would normally inject POJOs or simple DTOs in your spring services? Thanks

Comment: Not quite, if you look at chrylis's comment. is your weather class meant to contain stateful data and instantiated many times? if so, it shouldn't be a bean and instead a service class (as a bean) should be used to set its state and create many Weather objects.